# How to find words separated by a '=' sign using re.findall()

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm reading a file which contains the next:

```
//some text

Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE4[0] = -1073.40295735

//some more text

Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE11[1] = 1099.13456362

//some more text

Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE13[2] = 1025.13456362
```

I use `re.findall('Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch ([\w\.-]+)')` and I am able to find all three names `'B1_TE16...'` without the index numbers.

Now, what I would like to achieve is the next output:

```
[('B1_TE16_B1_TE4[0]', '-1073.40295735'), ('B1_TE16_B1_TE11[1]', '1099.13456362'), ('B1_TE16_B1_TE13[2]', '1025.13456362')]
```

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch ([\w.-]+\[\d+])\s*=\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD5RgE/1)

**Details**

- `([\w.-]+\[\d+])` - Group 1: one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `[`, 1 or more digits and then a `]`
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(-?\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 2: an optional `-`, 0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/feZK5K):

```
import re
s = """//some text
Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE4[0] = -1073.40295735
//some more text
Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE11[1] = 1099.13456362
//some more text
Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch B1_TE16_B1_TE13[2] = 1025.13456362"""
rx = r'Integral of Qr over area magnitude of patch ([\w.-]+\[\d+])\s*=\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+)'
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => [('B1_TE16_B1_TE4[0]', '-1073.40295735'), ('B1_TE16_B1_TE11[1]', '1099.13456362'), ('B1_TE16_B1_TE13[2]', '1025.13456362')]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! (Also, thank you for the demo, really helpful)